# Platform specific code in Flutter integration tests

Tags: testing, flutter, integration, platform

I have an integration test that has to open a time picker, but each platform has a different implementation of time picker. Therefor the flow of the integration test must differ between Android and iOS.. how can I achieve this?

I tried using the Platform class like this inside the test file, but it doesnt work:

```
//* 5) Choose time
      await driver.tap(find.byValueKey('addRideTimePicker'));
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        await driver.tap(find.text("V REDU"));
      }

      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        await driver.tap(find.text("OK"));
      }
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet, sadly.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32927 According to this issue it's currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you implemented `TimePicker`, but usually `CupertinoTimePicker` is the widget that renders the time picker on screen. Also, depending on where do you want to show it on screen, using `CupertinoTimePicker`, it renders equally from UI perspective on both platforms. For example, you may show the `time picker` inside `Container` or inside `bottomsheet`. A sample code to show time picker inside `bottomsheet` is as below:

```
body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Click'),
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext builder) {
              return Container(
                child: time()
              );
            });
          },
        )
      ),

Widget time() {
    return CupertinoTimerPicker(
      mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.hms,
      minuteInterval: 1,
      secondInterval: 1,
      initialTimerDuration: initialtimer,
      onTimerDurationChanged: (Duration changedtimer) {
        setState(() {
          initialtimer = changedtimer;
        });
      },
    );

  }
```

Above code shows time picker equally on both platforms as below:

[image]

[image]

This way, you may not need to use `Platform` class as you mentioned and directly in your `flutter driver` test, you may first identify the elements displayed in the `bottomsheet` and accordingly tap or perform actions you need.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesnt help me with my case. The thing is I want to have seperate timepickers for both platforms. Therefor the integration tests should be aware of the platform they are running on and change the behaviour accordingly